# How to check for homoscedasticity in a mixed effect model with longitudinal data in r

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity, levenes-test

I am new to using mixed effect models and all the information online has me quite confused. I hope someone can help me.

I have data of patients who did the same test at three different timepoints. I want to use a mixed effect model (lme4 package) to look at effect of time on change in score. I added an example data set below. I have 3 variables. (1) The person who did the test (2) the change in score (3) if the change in score was between timepoints 1 and 2 (t12) or 1 and 3 (t13). I fitted the mixed effect model below with 'Timepoint' as a fixed effect and 'Patient' as a random effect (hoping this is correct).

```
model <- lmer(Change_score ~ Timepoint + (1|Patient), data=Example_data)
```

If im correct I now have the model but im struggling to plot the standardized residuals and do the Levene's test to see if the data has homoscedasticity.

Example dataset:

```
structure(list(Patient = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), Timepoint = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("t12", "t13"), class = "factor"), 
    Change_score = c(10, 0, 7, 15, -3, 13, 9, -4, 2, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To plot the standardized residuals I found some information online suggesting I should do use the code below. This does give me a plot but I don't understand at all what im seeing on the plot and I feel like this is not what im looking for. I want to visualise the residuals from the model to asses homoscedasticity.

```
plot(model, resid(., type="pearson") ~ fitted(.), abline=0)
```

I tried doing the Levene's test (see code below) but due to missing values I get the error "Error in model.frame.default(form) : variable lengths differ (found for 'Example_data$Timepoint')" and I can't find a way to do the analysis with missing data.

```
Example_data$Timepoint <- as.factor(Example_data$Timepoint)
leveneTest(residuals(model) ~ Example_data$Timepoint)
```

I hope someone can help me with some sugestion on how to visualise the residuals and test for homoscedasticity in my data.